# front divs moves when browser is resized

Tags: html, css, resize, overflow

I'm doing a simple website.
In this website I have several divs in different layers (one in front of the other and so on).
With the two divs in the back there's no problem, but with the divs in the front when I resize the browser they move and I don't want that.
The weird part is that the back divs are created in the same way.
So basically what's messing my page around are: **#icone_esquerda** and **#icone_direita**.
Below is my code:

```
<style type="text/css">

#fundo{
    background-image:url("tileable_wood_texture_copy.png"); 
    background-repeat:repeat;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;  
    height:100%;    
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

#frente{
    background-image:url("luinguica.png"); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top center;
    position:fixed;
    width:inherit;  
    height:inherit; 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index:50;
}

#icone_esquerda{
    background-image: url("botao_facebook.png");
    background-position: bottom center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
    left: 45%;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 45%;
    width: 50px;
    z-index: 60;       
}

#icone_direita{
    background-image: url("botao_mail.png");
    background-position: bottom center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: fixed;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 53%;
    top: 45%;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
    z-index: 60;
```

}

```
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="fundo">
     <div id="frente">    
         <a href="http://www.facebook.com/confrariadaempada">
            <div id="icone_esquerda">
            </div>
         </a>
         <a href="mailto:info@confrariadaempada.pt">
            <div id="icone_direita">
            </div>
         </a>
     </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

When I resize the browser the divs with the ids icone_esquerda and icone_direita move!!
Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Move in what sense? Try replicating your problem with in a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Comment: From what i see here, if you use % value, it's normal that it move, since their parents divs are sized with the window width

Answer (score 0):

`Fixed` is supposed to keep it in the specified area based on screen - where it is, what size it is, etc.

`Absolute` makes it stay put, no matter where or what size.

Really, both of them should rarely (if ever) be used. It's better to learn to use `Relative` positioned elements with floats as needed (cleared properly, of course).

Comment: I've tried with absolute but when the browser is resized the same problem occurs. I've tried to put it as relative but not with any luck.

Comment: What's the real issue with my page??PLease help!